# How to stop animation function based on received variable rather than a pre declared number of frames

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, arduino, python-multithreading

I am using the animation function to query an arduino I need it to query it at a rate of 20Hz and i am having no trouble doing this currently. My issue is that I stop the reading after a pre declared number of frames rather than when my variable hits a certain point. I worked around this by stoping the event source when the variable hits a specific point and i could delare the frames to some huge number that the arduino would never hit but would rather do it in a cleaner way.

Here is the code I am currently using this is in a tkinter GUI but for brevity i'll just add the important stuff:

```
def start(self):
    self.xdata = []
    self.ydata1 = []
    self.ydata2 = []
    self.k = 0
    self.limit = 300
    self.arduinoData.flushInput()
    self.points = int(float(self.Duration_cycle.get())*60*20) + 1
    self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
        self.fig,
        self.update_graph,
        frames=self.points,
        interval=1,
        repeat=False)
    self.arduinoData.write("<L>")
    self.running = True
    self.ani._start()


def update_graph(self, i):
    self.xdata.append(self.k)
    while (self.arduinoData.inWaiting()==0):
        pass
    x = self.arduinoData.readline()
    strip_data = x.strip()
    split_data = x.split(",")
    self.ydata1.append(int(split_data[0])/100)
    self.ydata2.append(int(split_data[1])/100)
    self.ydata3 = int(split_data[2])
    self.line1.set_data(self.xdata, self.ydata1)
    self.line2.set_data(self.xdata, self.ydata2)
    if self.k < 50:
        self.ax1.set_ylim(min(self.ydata1)-1, max(self.ydata1) + 1)
        self.ax1.set_xlim(0, self.k)
        self.ax2.set_ylim(min(self.ydata2)-1, max(self.ydata2) + 1)
        self.ax2.set_xlim(0, self.k)
    elif self.k >= 50:
        self.ax1.set_ylim(min(self.ydata1[self.k-49:self.k])-1, max(self.ydata1[self.k-49:self.k]) + 1)
        #self.ax1.set_ylim(-1, 11)
        self.ax1.set_xlim(self.xdata[self.k-49], self.xdata[self.k-1])
        self.ax2.set_ylim(min(self.ydata2[self.k-49:self.k])-1, max(self.ydata2[self.k-49:self.k]) + 1)
        #self.ax2.set_ylim(-1, 11)
        self.ax2.set_xlim(self.xdata[self.k-49], self.xdata[self.k-1])
    if self.ydata3 >= self.limit:
        #self.points - 1:
        self.ani.event_source.stop()
        self.running = False
        self.ani = None
        self.running = not self.running
    self.k += 1

def getData(self):
    if self.ani is None:
        self.k = 0
        self.points = int(float(self.Duration_cycle.get())*60*20) + 1
        self.arduinoData.flushInput()
        self.arduinoData.write("<L>")
        return self.start()
    else:
        #self.k = 1
        self.arduinoData.write("<L>")
        self.arduinoData.flushInput()
        self.ani.event_source.start()
    self.running = not self.running
```

Comment: Are the two questions in any way related? No! If you have two questions, ask two questions.

Comment: Are you asking how to run this indefinitely? Set `repeat=True` and delete the `frames=self.points,` line.

Comment: Thank you for the help Novel that's what I was looking for. I should have asked a separate question for the other part

Comment: @Novel so if your comment actually solves the issue, could you provide this as an answer, which can be accepted?